# I want to open the same link multiple times, all in different browser sessions

Tags: java

This way it opens all the url in different tabs. All I want to do is open them in different sessions/windows.

```
import java.io.IOException;

public class For1 {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
            String url_open ="www.google.com";
            try {
                java.awt.Desktop.getDesktop().browse(java.net.URI.create(url_open));
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The `java.awt.Desktop.browse` method uses the default browser of your user profile, as the Javadoc says:

> Launches the default browser to display a URI. If the default browser
>   is not able to handle the specified URI, the application registered
>   for handling URIs of the specified type is invoked. The application is
>   determined from the protocol and path of the URI, as defined by the
>   URI class.

What you can do however, is to start the browser process using the `java.lang.ProcessBuilder` to start the browser process. That way you can set parameters to the browser's process such as the URL and the command to start as a new window. The following code starts firefox and chrome. You should change the filepath of each browser to match with your browser installation. If you use a different browser you should check what command line parameter it requires to start a new window.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
            String url_open ="www.google.com";
            try {
                new ProcessBuilder("C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Firefox Developer Edition\\firefox.exe", "-new-window", url_open).start();
                new ProcessBuilder("C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Google\\Chrome\\Application\\chrome.exe", "/new-window", url_open).start();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

you should try this solution

```
String[] args = new String[] { "C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Mozilla Firefox\\firefox.exe", "http://www.google.com" };
Runtime.getRuntime().exec( args );
```